# so files from build.gradle has different size with cmdline ndk-build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, ndk-build

I'm use 2 way to generate so.But the result has different size.

[image: use gradle to generate so]

[image: gradle result]

[image: use cmdline ndk-build to generate so]

[image: ndk-build result]

1.Using gradle to generate so

gradle result

so file is 53.4k
2.Using cmdline ndk-build to generate so

ndk-build result

so file is 25.1k

This is my Andoid.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := HelloA
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing exactly the parameters you use to build with each method, but I'd bet there are different optimisation flags, and thus you get different sizes.

Comment: I think I added all parameters in my quesition.